# Rails - Knowing the model/action from a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a basic route :

```
get '/patients/:id/edit', to: 'patients#edit', as: 'patient_edit'
```

From the path "patient_edit_path", it is possible to reverse the link to have the model (Patient) and action (edit) linked?

Comment: what do you actually want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path`

Example:

```
patient_id = 1
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(patient_edit_path(patient_id))
=> {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"patients", :id=>"1"}
```